# How to set initial state of div element to hide

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple function which shows or hides a div tag on clicking a button but how can i set it to initially be hiding and after clicking the button it is displayed?

Comment: `<div style="display:none">Nya nya, can't see me</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it's `display` style property to `None`.

```js
element = document.getElementById('toggle');
button = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
function hideAndShow(){
  if(element.style.display == 'none'|| element.style.display == '')    // checks if the display property is set to none or not
  {
    element.style.display = 'Block';  // if set to none then set the display property to block
    button.innerHTML = 'Hide';  // changes the button's text
    
  }
  else{
    element.style.display = 'None';   // otherwise set it to none
    button.innerHTML = 'Show';
  }
}
```

```css
#toggle{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: None;  /*this set's the divison to a hidden state by default*/
  background-color: rgba(248,25,34,0.8);
}

#toggle-button{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: rgba(25,25,67,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id='toggle'></div>
<button id='toggle-button' onclick='hideAndShow()'>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  };
```

Comment: this is not what he wanted, **read the question again carefully**. He wants to set the div to be initially hided. something like `<div style="display:none">`will achieve what he wants

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle() {
document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="hide">Test</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btnClick(){
  const divElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  if (divElement.classList.contains("show")) {
    divElement.classList.remove("show")
    divElement.classList.add("hide")
  } else {
    divElement.classList.add("show")
    divElement.classList.remove("hide")
  }
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none
}

.show{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="hide">
Hello, I am Div HTML Content
</div>
<button onclick="btnClick()">Click Me!!</button>
```